# Android: Any faster way of generate PDF into images and drawing onto the pdf.

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, processing-efficiency

I am currently using Xfinium PDF to generate pdf into images and do some drawing on to the pdf using their Graphics api e.g. drawing cubic paths.

There is a constructor PdfFixedDocument which I used it to load the document. The problem is when I tried to load a 30mbyte document to get the page information it would take 10+second to call the PdfFixedDocument constructor which is quite inefficient if I just want to fetch the page information or just loading a single page.

Does anyone have any better idea? I can't use PDFRender on android because I am running kitkat. Will there be a better api which can give me a better efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting a single page you can open the file using the PdfFile class and then extract the page using the PdfFile.ExtractPage method. 
You can also extract the basic page information (width, height, rotation) using the PdfFile.ExtractPageInfo method.

The PdfFixedDocument constructor loads the entire file into memory and maps it to XFINIUM.PDF object model so that any object can be easily updated and depending on the objects in the PDF file this can take some time.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library.

Comment: I could find ExtractPageInfo method in my android library

Comment: The convertPageToImage take average 5seconds to extract an image. I lower the quality but still not much of a different.

Comment: @Simon Please contact our support for an updated assembly that contains the ExtractPageInfo method.